# C++ BAD_ACCES error (code 1)

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers, hashtable

I'm making a C++ program "Hash Table"
I've spent 2 days debugging this piece of code but I still don't understand what's wrong.
I'm using xCode and it says "Build Failed" and gives this message

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x110)

Here is the pieces of my code, I'd really appreciate your any help!

**hash.cpp**

```
#include "hash.h"

size_t HashTable::hash_s(const Key &k){ /* simple hash function just to see how collisions are handled */
return (k.length());
}

HashTable::HashTable(): size_(0), numberOfLoaded(0){} /* constructor */

HashTable::~HashTable() { /* destructor */
delete [] hashTable;
}

void HashTable::allocate(){ /* function for memory allocation */

if (empty()){ /* if hashTable is empty, allocate memory for one element */
    size_ = 1;
    hashTable = new hashTableElement[size_];
    hashTable->k  = nullptr;
    hashTable->value = nullptr;
    return;
} else { /* if hashTable is not empty (at least has 1 element */
    hashTableElement *newHashTable = new hashTableElement[size_*2]; /* allocate memory for new double-sized array */

    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++ ){
        if (hashTable[i].k != nullptr){ /* copy all not empty array elements into the new double-sized array */
            size_t newIndex = hash_s(*(hashTable[i].k)) % (size_*2); /* count new index for double-sized array */
            newHashTable[newIndex] = hashTable[i];
        }
    }

    delete [] hashTable; /* delete memory from small table */

    size_ *= 2;

    hashTable = newHashTable;
    }
}

bool HashTable::insert(const Key &k, const Value &v){

allocate(); /* call allocation function */

size_t index = hash_s(k) % size_; /* index is a reminder of hash_s divided by size of the table */

hashTableElement *currentElement = &hashTable[index]; /* set a pointer to the currentElement */

/*problem is here EXC_BAD ACCESS (code=1, address=0x110)*/    while (currentElement->next) currentElement = currentElement->next; /* move to the last element in collision chain */

if ((currentElement->value != nullptr) || (currentElement != &hashTable[index])){ /* allocate memory for next element */
    currentElement->next = new hashTableElement;
    currentElement = currentElement->next;
}

currentElement->value = new Value; /* allocate memory for structure */
currentElement->k = new Key; /* allocate memory for key */

*(currentElement->k) = k; /* set to new element key value the value of inserted element */
*(currentElement->value) = v; /* set to new element value */

numberOfLoaded++; /* increment counter of inserted elements */
return true;
}

bool HashTable::empty() const{
for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++){
    if( hashTable[i].value != nullptr ){ /* if in the table at least one element inserted, return false */
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "hash.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void HashTable::print(){ /* function that prints entire table */
for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++){

    hashTableElement *newelement = &hashTable[i]; /* set a pointer to current element */

    while ((newelement) && (newelement->value != nullptr)){ /* printing all collisions chain */
        cout << *(newelement->k) << " " << newelement->value->age << " " << newelement->value->weight << endl;
        cout << "I = " << i << " Number Of loaded = " << numberOfLoaded << " Size of Table = "<< size_ <<endl;
        cout << "_____________________"<<endl;
        newelement = newelement->next; /* go to the next element in the chain */
    }
}
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

HashTable hashObj;
string name;
Value val;
Key k;

ifstream ins("/Users/Aeon/Documents/Study/NSU/Programming/Lab Works/2_Level/2_hash_table/Realization/input2.txt");

if (!ins.is_open()){

    cout << "File can't be open!\n"<<endl;

} else {

    while (ins >> k){ /* read a key (which is person's name) */

        ins >> val.age; /* read an age */
        ins >> val.weight; /* read a weight */
        hashObj.insert(k, val); /* call insert function */
    }
}

hashObj.print(); /* print an entire table */

return 0;
}
```

**hash.h**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef std::string Key;

struct Value {
unsigned int age;
unsigned int weight;
};

struct hashTableElement {
Value *value;
Key *k;
hashTableElement *next;
};

class HashTable {
private:
unsigned int numberOfLoaded;

size_t size_;

hashTableElement *hashTable;

void allocate(); /* function for memory allocation */

public:
HashTable(); /* constructor */

~HashTable(); /* destructor */

size_t hash_s(const Key &k); /* simple hash function */

void print(); /* function prints entire table */

bool insert(const Key& k, const Value& v); /* function inserts an element into the table */

bool empty() const; /* function returns true if HashTable is empty, false if not */
};

#endif /* defined(__Lab_Hash__hash__) */
```

Also, I just uploaded my test files:
[input2](http://textuploader.com/o44h)
[input](http://textuploader.com/o44x)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not including the *logical* mistakes in this code (think about what happens when `empty()` returns true?), right now they're overshadowed by bigger ones: you didn't post **all** the code required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I just added all the code. 
I think, 'empty()' returns true when there is no memory allocated in the array. If so, I allocate memory for 1 element. After that, if I need more memory, 'else' is working and I double 'size_' each time, when _coefficient of load_ is **70% or more**

Comment: Its not the same code, and still cannot compile. `hash_s` is fully defined both in the header and the .cpp file. Also, `allocation` is declared in the class taking a `HashTable` parameter (for reasons-unknown), while `allocate` is the name actually implemented in the .cpp file taking a `Key` parameter, but not mentioned whatsoever in the class declaration. And fyi, your table expansion doesn't account whatsoever for collisions during reassignment. Once again, please, *please*, post the **real** code exhibiting the **real** problem you're having.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry! I really have posted some weird staff, my bad. Now I edited everything, added my input files and also commented everything.

Comment: Ultimately a huge problem is your rehash chaining (plain-and-simple, there isn't any). When you expand the table the existing nodes in any *old* collision chain are not guaranteed to all hash to the same *new* slot. Each one has to be checked. This is *much* easier with a dynamic array of pointers (and truth be told, `unordered_map`, but I realize this is for academia). [**Example: see here**](http://pastebin.com/nACvhJ57). I've left most of the operators, duplicate detection, etc, for you to code, but the chaining of new values and table expansion should be self-explanatory. best of luck.

Comment: Oh, thank you sooo much! 
Thank you for you time you've spent on stupid me.. Now I understand my mistakes.. Thank you again